Covariance of solutions of stochastic differential equations
Consider two SDEs: $$dX_t=αX_t dt+βX_t dB_t^{(1)}$$$$
dY_t=γY_t dt+δY_t dB_t^{(2)}$$
Brownian motions $B_t^{(1)}$ and $B_t^{(2)}$ are independent.
Prove that $cov(X_t,Y_t)=0$.
I've found the solution to the SDEs and showed this directly.
But it is tedious and cumbersome.
Is there a more elegant approach?

It is probably a bit less tedious to realize that you need to solve only one of those SDEs. :) . Also: they are so common that anyone working with them should know the solution by heart.

@KurtG. , I mean is there an approach with solving the SDEs explicitly? Maybe to write in the integral form and then use the definition?

As far as I understood that was the approach you used. Do you have a typo somewhere? Due to a result of Yamada & Watanabe (see book of Karatzas & Shreve) every solution of a well behaved SDE is of the form $X=h(X_0, B)$ where $h(X_0,,.,)$ is a functional of the Brownian path. This also implies not only zero covariance of $X$ and $Y$ but also their independence. I strongly advise against using such abstract theorems as long as you still find solving those SDEs tedious and cumbersome.

The drift and diffusion parts have no dependence between the two, namely, these are not coupled equations and the Brownian motions are assumed independent. It seems you are overcomplicating the problem.

Here is an "elegant" method. Firstly, note that $\mathrm{Cov}(X_t,Y_t) = \Bbb{E}[X_tY_t] - \Bbb{E}[X_t]\Bbb{E}[Y_t]$. Secondly, after averaging the SDEs, one also has $\Bbb{E}[\mathrm{d}X_t] = \alpha\Bbb{E}[X_t]\mathrm{d}t$, which is a mere ODE solved by $\Bbb{E}[X_t] = \Bbb{E}[X_0]e^{\alpha t}$, and similarly $\Bbb{E}[Y_t] = \Bbb{E}[Y_0]e^{\gamma t}$. Next, use Itô's product rule in order to write
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}(X_tY_t) 
   &= Y_t\mathrm{d}X_t + X_t\mathrm{d}Y_t + d[X,Y]_t \\
   &= X_tY_t \left((\alpha + \gamma)\mathrm{d}t + \beta\mathrm{d}B_t^{(1)} + \delta\mathrm{d}B_t^{(2)} + \beta\delta\mathrm{d}B_t^{(1)}\mathrm{d}B_t^{(2)}\right)
\end{align}
$$
hence $\Bbb{E}[X_tY_t] = \Bbb{E}[X_0Y_0]e^{(\alpha + \gamma)t}$ thanks to the same reasoning. Finally, it leads to $\mathrm{Cov}(X_t,Y_t) = \mathrm{Cov}(X_0,Y_0)e^{(\alpha + \gamma)t}$.

What do you mean when say "averaging the SDEs"?

@PaulR. I mean applying the expectation operator $\Bbb{E}$. In addition, I have edited my answer in order to correct a small error,

Covariance should be zero! I guess you meant $\mathrm{Cov}(X_t,Y_t)=\Bbb{E}[X_0Y_0]e^{(\alpha + \gamma)t}-\Bbb{E}[X_0]e^{\alpha t}\Bbb{E}[Y_0]e^{\gamma t}=0$.
